# What is considered a "domestic flight" with Delta flights in North America?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, international-travel, delta-air-lines

```
Carry-on Baggage - complimentary
```

so that's easy.

Then we get to the checked luggage:

```
   First Checked Bag - Within U.S. and Canada: $25 USD
                       U.S./Canada and Caribbean: $25 USD
                       International: Complimentary
```

I won't bother with the other details (like size, second checked bag), but my question is - it's ambiguous (to me) - is Canada TO the US $25 or complimentary?

Comment: in North America flights across the Canadian and US border are rarely called international. But double check because occasionally, they are. When you see a list that includes "Canada/US" as one item and "International" as another, I would say that is very clear. Your bag will cost $25.

Comment: Some bits of the Caribbean also count as "domestic" on many US airlines, but I don't think Mexico ever does. Airlines use some rather odd definitions...!

Comment: +1 Kate Gregory. Large Canadian airports will have three sections: Domestic, USA and International.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within US and Canada its $25, and they don't mention specifically that its only from the US to Canada, so I would assume that its both ways. To the best of my knowledge flights to/from Canada are considered "domestic" for all terms and purposes, so I see no reason why the luggage would be an exception.

Comment: just found this: http://airtravel.about.com/od/luggageandpackingadvice/a/dlbags.htm which seems to disagree, but then it's about.com, rather than Delta, so grain of salt and all that... :/

Comment: Does Delta have a domestic Canadian flight, i.e.: Delta flying between two Canadian airports? I don't think they have.

Comment: Sadly, you were right, they insisted it's a "Domestic flight" :/

Answer (score 1):

"within US and Canada" -> not crossing the border, so your departure and destination are in the same country (say Atlanta to Buffalo, NY)
"U.S./Canada and Caribbean" -> departure and destination in different countries (so say New York to Montreal).

Comment: See my comment on the other answer - Delta confirms that a Canada -> US flight is a DOMESTIC flight.  Weasels, but that's how they record it.